# TabBarController - first view is offset by 20px

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

This is driving me crazy. I have a tab bar controller, which is pushed into a navigation controller stack.

The first view controller of the tab bar has an image, which has two constraints:

- 0 to top layout guide
- 0 to bottom layout guide

But when the tab bar controller gets pushed, and the first view controller appears for the first time, the aforementioned image is offset by 20pixels for no particular reason.

Comment: You using storyboard or coding ?

Comment: Storyboard, I'm firing performSegueWithIdentifier:sender from code.

Comment: Some problem shpuld be there with constraints only..

Comment: iOS7. And I don't see why it would be a problem with constraints if I go to a different tab, then back to the first, everything is normal.

Comment: @LordZsolt - please post pic of storyboard in the question for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it by doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    //I need to do this, otherwise the scrollview is offset by 20 pixels when first displayed (I HAVE NO IDEA WHY....)
    if (self.scrollView.frame.origin.y == 20) {
        [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 20)];
    }
}
```

Though I have no idea why it only messes up at first display...

Comment: Did you put this in the TabBarController or in one of the tabs' controllers? I got so excited to find a solution to this annoying problem but I can't get it to work!

Comment: I've put it into the tab bar controllers FIRST `view controller`.

Comment: Ah GREAT! I had to figure out a little modification to the code, but it finally worked. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Just another comment, I noticed that this will occur when the user is on any tab (not just the initial) and then they rotate the screen. So I would be sure to put the code in every view in the tabBarController

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try this out. Put this line in viewDidLoad of your fist view controller of navigation controller.

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem. A label in the first view of the tabview controller ignores the 8px margin from top. When that view was first time loaded, the space is more than 20, but when i switch to the second tab and come back, the problem disappears.

Simulator when first open the view with the wrong space

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKxMs.jpg

Simulator when i switch to the second tab and come back, then with the right space

https://i.stack.imgur.com/teUyl.jpg

Comment: This is not an answer to the question... consider adding additional information you have to a comment.